# HashMap containsKey() returns false although hashCode() and equals() are true

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<Vertex, Integer>` called `vertexIndexes`. If I iterate through it with this code:

```
public boolean search(String vertexName){
    for (Vertex name: vertexIndexes.keySet()){        
        String key =   name.toString();
        String value = vertexIndexes.get(name).toString();              
        System.out.println(key + " " + value + " "+ (name.hashCode() == vertexName.hashCode()) + " " + name.equals(vertexName));  
    }
...
}
```

it produces this output:

```
Diessen 0 false false
Herrsching 5 false false
Schondorf 2 false false
Greifenberg 3 false false
Stegen 4 false false
Utting 1 false false
Andechs 6 false false
Fischen 7 true true
```

So you can see, that the Vertex `Fischen` is present and the `hashCode` and `equals` methods work fine. But if I run

```
vertexIndexes.containsKey("Fischen")
```

it returns `false`.

Why is that? I lose my mind over it.

Comment: So the keys are instances of `Vertex`, not of `String`? But the key you are checking for is a `String`. A `String` will never be equal to anything but another `String`.

Comment: As you can see in my output (..true true..): I implemented the toString() and equals method of Vertex to correctly compare it to a String.

Comment: `toString()` is irrelevant, and even if your `Vertex` instance claims to be equal to a `String`, the `String` instance will _not_ say it is equal to a `Vertex`.

Comment: @khelwood unless in a very alternative implementation of an equals method :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: You key types are different. Your maps keyset is of type Vertex and you are passing string to contains method of map.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`name.equals(vertexName)` compares a `Vertex` to a `String`. While your `Vertex` class `equals` method might return `true` when you pass a `String` to it, `String`'s `equals` will never return `true` when you pass a `Vertex` to it.

`HashMap` probably tests whether `vertexName.equals(name)`, which returns `false`.

Change

```
vertexIndexes.containsKey("Fischen")
```

to

```
vertexIndexes.containsKey(new Vertex("Fischen"))
```

or change the key of your `Map` to `String`.

BTW, you could have avoided that issue in the first place if you followed the contract of the `equals` method that appears in the Javadoc of the `Object` class:

> • It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

Your `equals` implementation is not symmetric.